# Erase paths that are redrawn out of a List

Tags: android, path, drawing, erase

I've been working on a drawing app for Android lately and I am now facing a problem I cannot solve.
The idea is to be able to draw on two drawing layers. When changing to the 2nd layer you only see the drawings of this layer, while being in the 1st layer you see both layers with the 2nd being slightly transparent.

To do this I have two lists which save the drawn paths and paints.

```
case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
    //save a path to the list
    Paint strokePaint=new Paint();
    Path strokePath=new Path();
    setupDrawingPaint(strokePaint); //some initialization           
    stroke = new Stroke(strokePath, strokePaint); //object to save the paths
    stroke.movePath(touchX, touchY);

    if(drawingLayer==1){
        strokeListL1.add(stroke);
    }
    else{
        strokeListL2.add(stroke);
    }

    //draw the path
    drawingPath.moveTo(touchX, touchY);
    break;

case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:           
    stroke.linePath(touchX, touchY);
    drawingPath.lineTo(touchX, touchY);
    break;

case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:             
    canvas.drawPath(drawingPath, drawingPaint);
    drawingPath.reset()             
    break;

invalidate();
```

Now in the onDraw()-Method the path is drawn normally except when the layer was changed, then the stroke objects from the list are drawn.

```
canvas.drawBitmap(canvasBitmap, 0, 0, canvasPaint);
    //draw the layer(s)
    if(layerChanged)
    {
        if(drawingLayer==1){
            for(Stroke stroke : strokeListL1)
                canvas.drawPath(stroke.getPath(), stroke.getPaint());
            for(Stroke stroke : strokeListL2){
                Paint paint = stroke.getPaint();
                paint.setAlpha(50);
                canvas.drawPath(stroke.getPath(), paint);
            }
        }
        else{
            for(Stroke stroke : strokeListL2){
                Paint paint = stroke.getPaint();
                paint.setAlpha(255);                
                canvas.drawPath(stroke.getPath(), paint);   
            }
        }
    }
    else
        canvas.drawPath(drawingPath, drawingPaint);
    layerChanged=false;
```

And here start the problems. As long as I dont change the layers erasing is working fine but as soon as i do change the layers instead of erasing it just clears the whole canvas. 
The erase method looks like this:

```
public void setErase(boolean erase){
    eraseMode=erase;
    if(eraseMode)
        drawingPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));        
    else
        drawingPaint.setXfermode(null);
}
```

If I do some erasing before a layer change the "erasing strokes" will be drawn in a color too, once i change back to that layer. I am not sure if i maneuvered myself into a dead end or if I am just not getting it. Hope you guys can help me out.

So far

Answer (score 0):

Okay so this error was dumb. The problem was the Paint object being reinitialized everytime a new Path is drawn by the User. That, of course, will unset the set Xfermode.

```
case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
Paint strokePaint=new Paint();
```

The solution is to give the current Paint object to the constructor.

```
Paint strokePaint=new Paint(drawingPaint);
```